# SQLiteException: Table has no column

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hey guys i have a problem here in sqlexception. im doing is im adding a column for my database and then this happen how to fix this issue? can you please help me im newbie in android developing.

my sqlitehelper

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static String DATABASE_NAME="AndroidJSonDataBase";

public static final String TABLE_NAME="AndroidJSonTable";

public static final String Table_Column_ID="id";

public static final String Table_Column_1_Name="name";

public static final String Table_Column_2_PhoneNumber="phone_number";

public static final String Table_Column_3_Birth="birth";
public static final String Table_Column_4_Course="course";
public static final String Table_Column_5_Email="email";
public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+Table_Column_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+Table_Column_3_Birth+"VARCHAR,"+Table_Column_4_Course+"VACHAR,"+Table_Column_5_Email+"VARCHAR, "+Table_Column_1_Name+" VARCHAR, "+Table_Column_2_PhoneNumber+" VARCHAR)";
    database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

}
```

My logcat

```
02-28 00:08:46.019 4298-4298/com.example.lightning.beats E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.lightning.beats, PID: 4298
                                                                        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table AndroidJSonTable has no column named birth (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO AndroidJSonTable (name,phone_number,birth,course,email) VALUES('ghh','556','555', 'gg','ggg');
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:891)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:502)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
                                                                            at com.example.lightning.hannah.Basura.prof.InsertDataIntoSQLiteDatabase(prof.java:99)
                                                                            at com.example.lightning.hannah.Basura.prof$1.onClick(prof.java:48)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18451)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:979)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: so you are adding a new column in your previous database?

Comment: Im adding this "public static final String Table_Column_3_Birth="birth";
public static final String Table_Column_4_Course="course";
public static final String Table_Column_5_Email="email";" and then it crashed when i click the button add data.

Comment: On what line is the exception thrown?

Comment: the original column of this is "name and phone number" then im trying to add the 3 after that it wont work again

Comment: Of course, you need a **space** here: `"+Table_Column_3_Birth+"VARCHAR,` before `VARCHAR`. And also on the next 2 fields.

Comment: I dont understand a little bit.  Can you show me how to do this?

Comment: You're kidding me.

Comment: I already fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just uninstall your application from your device and install again by rebuilding it. The problem here is that you've added the new column later into your code, but the actual database which is already there in your device has no such columns. So you need to create the database again.

One better approach is, drop and recreate all tables in `onUpdate` method, and increase the `db` version every time you change the schema.

Comment: The table is not correctly created due to mystyping. The OP forgot some **spaces**.

Comment: @madara09 just uninstall the app from your device and re install it from your android studio. As you were doing before.

Comment: Still crashed. It say "sqliteexception autoincrement is only allowed on an integer primary key

Comment: @madara09 yeah so remove auto increment wherever you've applied it on non-integer keys.

Comment: This.. works... unusual.. Hope my users won't have to reinstall their app.